# Scan for keyboard input without pausing

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to have R periodically check for keyboard input from the graphics window and then continue execution if there is none. There is a `repeat` loop that continuously updates graphics in the window, and I would like it to react to some keyboard input, but not **wait** for input. However, I'm only aware of commands like `scan` or `getGraphicsEvent` that pause execution until input is received.

Is there a way to, basically, scan the keyboard buffer and just continue execution if it is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Event-driven progamming in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming

In OOP one solution could consist of:

- A object containing public methods that will be called when the event ocurs. What has to be done when the event ocurs.
- A parallel thread that will continously check for a key to be pressed. When this happens that thread will call the previous method.

I'm not familiarized with R but you should search in the API, maybe the language provides listeners to manage key events.